# Stitching user IDs for click tracking

Tags: python, sql, r, data-cleaning

My company uses a tag management platform that attempts to perform user stitching in its click tracking tables. I've found that it's not even close to being watertight, and I'm exploring ways to perform that stitching on my own. What I have to work with is a series of IDs (why so many? Beats me) that pair to each other somewhat haphazardly. For one user, the data would look something like this:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C |  |
| A | D |  |
| A |  | E |
| A |  | F |
| B | C |  |
| B | D |  |
| B |  | E |
| B |  | F |

My goal is to create a new column that has stores one constant ID. I don't care which one, A/B/C/D/E/F, as long as it's constant and exhaustive across all records for a given user. Something like:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 | ID_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C |  | A |
| A | D |  | A |
| A |  | E | A |
| A |  | F | A |
| B | C |  | A |
| B | D |  | A |
| B |  | E | A |
| B |  | F | A |

I would *love* a SQL-based way of doing this, but I'd be open to an R- or Python-based solution as well. For R/Python, we'd probably spin up a dockerized job that performs the stitching and writes a lookup table to our warehouse. Thank you!!

A few edits based on initial feedback:

1. Added second table with visualization of the end result I'm trying to achieve.
2. FYI, Google Tag Manager is not the actual tag management platform. It doesn't actually matter what the actual tag manager is, this is more of a data wrangling task than a tag management task. I only mentioned tag management to provide context for where this question came up.

Comment: There is no way to know what you are looking for here.  What is your expected output?  What logical steps is that output based on?  Is this test data exhaustive all use cases?

Comment: Maybe this question is clear with knowledge of google-tag-manager for context, but as written it's hard to know what you are looking for. If you give some detail on what logical operations would be performed to arrive at this constant id or what the criteria for this field would be, people can help you implement that in sql/R/python. So if you put your expected value(s) for this constant id given this sample data, and what your reasoning is, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: @error_2646 knowledge of GTM (or any tag manager) is not a prerequisite for this question. This is ultimately a data wrangling question - how do I identify all records that come from the same 'source' (i.e., user). It's almost like an exercise in similarity.

Comment: It seems something important is missing from the question.  `My goal is to create a new column that has stores one constant ID. I don't care which one, A/B/C/D/E/F, as long as it's constant and exhaustive across all records for a given user.`  I assume you have a user identifier.  If you just need to tie this to a user, use that.

Comment: @Jon Armstrong - that's exactly the point of the question. There is no single user identifier. There are multiple identifiers that are inconsistently applied across records. When I say I don't care which one A/B/C/D/E/F, I just mean I have no preference which of the existing identifiers is applied as the final one, and I don't need to make a NEW identifier (i.e., not generating a new string to serve as key). In the above table, where it says ID_final, it says "A" across all rows but that's just an example. Could be all B's, all C's, etc.

Comment: @Wags So, if you had a few more rows in the sample data {X, Null, Y, Z}, {X, W, V, Null},{V, U, T, S} Any one of S,T,U,V,X,Y,Z (and no others) could be the constant id for all for rows?

Comment: @Wags What DBMS are you using? This is an interesting problem, I really doubt there's a non-procedural sql approach to do it.

Comment: So you're suggesting that `A,B,C,D,I`, is a list of possible unique identifiers for one and only one user over all sampled data.  So rows which have any overlap in one of these ids (any column compared with any other column) is guaranteed to identify the same user?  Is the following an example of one and only one user (given only 2 columns in this example)?  `row1: A, B; row2: B, C; row3: C, D; row4: D, E` ?

Comment: @Error_2646 - Our warehouse is Redshift, which uses PostgreSQL. And if I'm understanding you extra rows correctly, it sounds like you're suggesting dummy data for a second user where those values S/T/U/V/X/Y/Z are the their various ID values. In which case, yes, I'd want a fourth column that has any one of those values displayed constantly across all rows for that second user. (although FWIW, in my toy example above, there are only 3 cols of IDs - the 4th col in the 2nd table is the hypothetical stitched ID that I'm after.

Comment: @Jon Armstrong - yes (minus "I" - not in my example). Your set of pairs is basically right - every person has a handful of each type of IDs that overlap somewhat randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I checked back in on this out of curiosity. This is by no means an answer, just an alternative way to pose the question. The way I'm understanding it, it's a graph problem. So if you phrase it like that you might get some looks from people with more chops with that.

```
dataset = [
    {'A': ['B','C']},
    {'A': ['D','E']},
    {'E': ['F','G']},
    {'S': ['T','U']},
    {'U': ['V','X']}]
```

Desired output - grouping of graphs by all sequences of shared nodes.

```
grouped_by_commonality = [
    {'common_id_1_grouping': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']},
    {'common_id_2_grouping': ['S','T','U','V','X']}]
```

Then you'd assign your common id based on membership of id_1,id_2,id_3 in your dataset.